# Concatenated rule applications (applying rules to rules correctly)

Tags: replacement, rule

I am trying to apply a series of individual rules onto an expression sequentially, but also not have to write out the repeated `ReplaceAll` functions each time I want to perform the same series of rules.

Here's an illustrative example of my problem:

```
(* r1, r2 and r3 are the individual rule transformations *)
r1[a_] := {a :> 3 a};
r2[a_] := {a :> -a};
r3[a_] := {a :> a + 1};

(* Try to define a single rule operator which applies rules in a given order *)
rall[a_] := r1[a] /. r2[a] /. r3[a];

(* Ideal answer is given by *)
a /. r1[a] /. r2[a] /. r3[a]
```

Which evaluates to `-3(a+1)`, applying each rule sequentially, whereas

```
a /. rall[a]
```

evaluates to `a`, having not applied any of the rules. This can be understood, since `rall[a]` evaluates to `{-a-1:>3(-(a+1))}`, having applied the rules `r2[a]` and `r3[a]` to the initial `r1[a]` term, not just the rhs instances of `a` in the rules expressions.

How can I build a composite rule function that achieves my aim? Is there a way to delay the evaluation of the rules stated in rall[a] until I apply it to a variable?

Comment: Functions are *already* based on replacement rules. You could write: `r1[a_] := 3a; r2[a_] := -a; r3[a_] := a+1; rall[a_] := r3@r2@r1[a]`, then try and evaluate `rall[a]`.

Comment: Well, obviously the logic of defining `rall[a_]` as you did it, is flawed. You instruct the second and third rule to act on the first, instead of all rules to act on some expression - and that is what you get. Why not doing something like `rall[a_] := Function[expr, expr /. r1[a] /. r2[a] /. r3[a]];`, and then `rall[a][a]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe with the help of `Fold` or `FoldList` :

See what happens here:

```
FoldList[#1 /. #2 &, a, {r1[a], r2[a], r3[a]}]
```

> {a, 3 a, -3 a, -3 (1 + a)}

Replace `FoldList` with `Fold` to get directly the last result.

In other words:

```
rall[a_] := Fold[#1 /. #2 &, a, {r1[a], r2[a], r3[a]}]
```

then

```
rall[a]
```

> -3 (1 + a)

Comment: That's great. How do I extend this to multiple rule arguments, say for `r1[a,b]`? I tried some variations on syntax such as `Fold[{#1,#2}/.#3 &[a,b], {r1[a,b],r2[a,b],r3[a,b]}]` but can't seem to find the correct extension.

Comment: @SLesslyTall Simply `Fold[#1 /. #2 &, expr[a,b], {r1[a, b], r2[a, b], r3[a, b]}]` where `expr[a,b]` stands for any initial expression you want to replace, for example `Sin[a]^b`, or any list `{a,b,a*b^2,...}`, ...